# Java/Maven compilation failure (no suitable constructor found)

Tags: java, maven, travis-ci

I ran into a strange problem..
I work on a project that use the [ProcessBuilder Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).
On my local machine (Java6 and Java7 tested) I can easily `mvn clean install` & `mvn assembly:single` the project without any errors. Now I want to let the project build by [travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org) and ran into to following error

> error: no suitable constructor found for ProcessBuilder(String)

[full log file here..](https://travis-ci.org/MultiServerControl/MineControl/jobs/4854648) 
but the [Javadoc for ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#ProcessBuilder%28java.lang.String...%29) show me that constructor.
My .travis.yml looks like this

> language: java
>
> jdk:
>     - oraclejdk7
>     - openjdk6
>     - openjdk7
>
> after_success:
>     - mvn assembly:single

Any ideas why the build fails on travis-ci?

Thanks, F481

**Edit:**
Locally I'm using Maven 3, like travis-ci too (travis doc: "Travis Java builder will use Maven 3 to build it.")
My pom.xml: https://github.com/MultiServerControl/MineControl/blob/master/pom.xml
And the java code of the first error: `this.processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("");`
The full class is available [here](https://github.com/MultiServerControl/MineControl/blob/master/src/main/java/com/multiservercontrol/minecontrol/ServerController.java)

**Edit2:**
I specified a source and target version for the maven compilation like this:

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0</version>
      <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
      </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now the build is working for JDK7: https://travis-ci.org/MultiServerControl/MineControl/jobs/5963859

But I don't get the reason for that behavior.. and I want to build the project for JDK 5,6 too.
How can I do that?

Comment: Probably it is openjdk compiler bug. And it cannot apply String to "public ProcessBuilder(String... command)" constructor..

Comment: Hm.. if so, why the oracle jdk build fails too on travis-ci? :P

Comment: @F481 Which version of maven are you running locally? And which version on travis? Can you show the `pom.xml` and the code calling `ProcessBuilder`?

Comment: @NilsH I've updated my question with a "Edit" section, that includes the answers to your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Very strange indeed. It seems to be related to varargs, since you also have other compilation failures in the same class (calling the `command` method). I'd suppose it would be resolved by excplicit calling the methods with `String[]` instead, but it wouldn't solve the mystery... Does other vararg invocations work? The first thing that came to mind was that it must have something to do with source or target versions used with `javac`, but I'm not sure how that would happen.

Comment: @NilsH I think you're right with your assumption of source and target version. Take a look at "Edit2".. I really don't know what to do so far :P

Comment: You get the same error if you specify source and target 1.5?

Comment: The build works now, after switching source and target version to 1.5. That's absolutly strange, because the default values of the maven compiler plugin for the source and target configuration is 1.5: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#target

Comment: Strange... Maybe it was picking up the wrong version of the maven compiler plugin for some reason. But great that you have it working now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I specified the version of the maven compiler plugin and the source and target version for the compilation like this:

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0</version>
      <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
      </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now the build is working! Much thanks to **NilsH** who pushed me in the right direction.